# creating a CRON job to just visit a page once a day without timing out

Tags: php, cron

I do not have any experience with Linux or CRON jobs at all. I have created my site and put all the daily tasks I need the CRON to do as a PHP function on a webpage. So all I need is a CRON job to simply visit the webpage once a day.

This is what I'm using. `wget -O - http://prayerpond.com/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

Starting out there isn't hardly anything populating the tables in the database, what concerns me is that there are so many tasks in the function that the page will time out when the tables get a ton of information in them.

Is this a valid concern? If so, is there something I can do to prevent this?

Comment: I would suggest you break your cron jobs out to separate scripts, and have them called at different times of the day to reduce the load on the server

Comment: If there are _so many tasks in the function that the page will time out_ you should most probably find a different way of handling (maybe queuing). Also, you're making a script that seems to do quite some stuff publicly available. This surely shouldn't be, better call it via cli and only have it privately on the server

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `--read-timeout=seconds` flag to `wget` to set a read timeout. A connection timeout would indicate that your server is probably not even up.

Answer (score 0):

To set up a cron job you can read this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job), then the cron job could be doing something like `php /path/to/project/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: This will run the actual php file and its functions?

Comment: @thinkofacard yes, unless php is not in your path then you have to use /usr/bin/php or wherever is placed in your system :)

Comment: Thank you Gori, it's not working though so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I put the cron.php in the root (and not the publichtml folder) so when I copy the location of the file in filezilla I get ftp://username@mysite.com/cron.php so I used php /cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1 but it's not running.

Comment: @thinkofacard you have to use the absolute path to the `cron.php` file

Comment: Okay this is a stupid question but how do I figure out the absolute path? What I thought was the absolute path isn't working. :-/ I tried moving it to the public_html folder and used /public_html/cron.php but that isn't working either.

Comment: @thinkofacard sorry I missunderstood that /public_html was a folder in the root, your path was correct. You can also execute the cron code manually from the command line to see the error output and know what is failing.

Comment: This is the error I get: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @thinkofacard never heard of this error, anyway this problem is not related with this question I guess, a quick search on google should help you to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to place the script outside the public folder and call the script with something like

```
php /the/path/to/your/phpscript/script.php
```